# Views 3 filter on academic year

Tags: views

Using Drupal 6, Views 3. I am trying to build a view that will include events for the current school year. So this year the view would include everything from September 2014 through June 2015. Once we got to July 1st 2015 the view would show the next year (Sept 2015 - June 2016).

I'm thinking this might be accomplished with arguments but I'm not sure.

Any kick in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Les Z

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/352973) useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Date filter inside views that can be set and customized easily to satisfy your needs. You need to enable the *Date module* first. Here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/date

If you find implementation using Date module difficult, you can achieve the same result using the straight forward *Views between dates filter module*:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_between_dates_filter

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using the date field already and while I can go in manually each year and update the range, what I was looking for was something that is not hard coded.